# Explanation for tail(?) recursion when calling the method twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's have the following code:

```
import time

def rec1(len):
    if( len < 2): return 1;
    return 2*rec1(len-1);

def rec2(len):
    if( len < 2): return 1;
    return rec2(len-1) + rec2(len-1);

def callAndReport(len, method):
    time1 = time.time()
    answer = method(len)
    time2 = time.time()
    print("{0} with {1}:{2} in {3:.0f} ms".format(len,method.__name__,answer, (time2-time1)*1000))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   callAndReport(20,rec1)
   callAndReport(20,rec2)
   print('')
   callAndReport(23,rec1)
   callAndReport(23,rec2)
```

This code produces the following output:

```
20 with rec1:524288 in 0 ms
20 with rec2:524288 in 642 ms

23 with rec1:4194304 in 0 ms
23 with rec2:4194304 in 4613 ms
```

Could someone explain the execution time difference? I have few ideas but I would like to be sure.

For completeness, the original problem I had was the method below (which can be easily express as a for loop, but that's not the point here):

```
def find11s_rec(len):
    if len<2: return 0
    if len== 2: return 1;   
    return find11s_rec(len-2)+find11s_rec(len-1)+2**(len-2)
```

.

Comment: `rec2` has what are called "overlapping sub-problems" - you are repeating work you have already done.

Comment: Neither is tail-recursive, which requires no operations be done on the result of the recursive call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because while `rec1` only uses `rec1` once, `rec2` uses `rec2` twice. And then those *inner* `rec2` calls will each call `rec2` twice. The number of function calls will rise exponentially. While `rec1` might use `x` calls, `rec2` would use `2^x` calls. In computer science terms, `rec1` is O(x) while `rec2` is O(2^x). In more complicated cases, dangerous recursion might inobvious; so use a debugger to find out what is actually being done.

Comment: Ha! How obvious. I didn't think about the 'branching' going on in subsequent calls. 2^x is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of `rec1` is O(n) and the complexity of `rec2` is O(2^n). That's a big performance difference.

```
rec2(n) = rec2(n-1) + rec2(n-1)
        = (rec2(n-2) + rec2(n-2)) + (rec2(n-2) + rec2(n-2)) = 4 * rec2(n-2)
          ...

rec2(n) = (2^n)*rec2(1)
        = O(2^n)
```